# Python how to fix year out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert timezones in a csv file, and the code that I am using for this used to work fine but for some reason it is giving me the error `dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: year 20200320 is out of range: 20200320.0 21:43:00`. This is weird because this error did not happen before with this code.

When I try to reproduce the error with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating sample dataframe
lst1 = [['Bananas', 'Bali', '20200108', '15:30:00', 1.58, 1.85, 1.50, 1.50],
['Bananas', 'Bali', '20200108', '22:00:00', 1.68, 1.78, 1.40, 1.60],
['Bananas', 'Bali', '20200109', '15:30:00', 1.88, 1.95, 1.70, 1.86],
['Bananas', 'Bali', '20200109', '22:00:00', 1.78, 1.88, 1.60, 1.65],
['Coconut', 'Bahamas', '20200110', '15:30:00', 2.58, 2.85, 2.50, 2.50],
['Coconut', 'Bahamas', '20200110', '22:00:00', 2.68, 2.78, 2.40, 2.60],
['Coconut', 'Bahamas', '20200111', '15:30:00', 2.88, 2.95, 2.70, 2.86],
['Coconut', 'Bahamas', '20200111', '22:00:00', 2.78, 2.88, 2.60, 2.65]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst1, columns =['Name', 'Origin', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'])
print('Second Dataframe')
print(df1)

df1["Datetime"] = df1["Date"].astype(str) + ' ' + df1["Time"].astype(str)
df1["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Datetime"])
df1["Datetime"] = df1["Datetime"].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Paris').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
df1["Datetime"] = df1["Datetime"].dt.tz_localize(None)
df1["Datetime"] = df1["Datetime"].astype(str)

print(df1)
```

it does not give me the error, eventhough it is the same code and data. I am verry confused by this and I hope that someone here is able to help me out.

I tried to divide the date by `1000.0`, which was an answer here on SO, but then it gives me an error that I cant do calculations with strings, but I also cannot convert the date to datetime64. I hope someone here knows how to fix this issue.

EDIT:
Here is a sample of the actual .csv file I am using. As you can see, it has lots of whitespaces, which i remove within the script.

```
Ticker;Exchange;Date;None;Time;Open; High;  Low;    Close;   Volume;   VWAP;      Trades      
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:00:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 10 ; 0.67 ; 3
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:01:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0 ; 0.67 ; 0
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:02:00 ; 0.66 ; 0.66 ; 0.66 ; 0.66 ; 4 ; 0.66 ; 1
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:03:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 3 ; 0.67 ; 1
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:04:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 4 ; 0.67 ; 1
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:05:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0 ; 0.67 ; 0
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:06:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0 ; 0.67 ; 0
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:07:00 ; 0.65 ; 0.65 ; 0.65 ; 0.65 ; 4 ; 0.65 ; 1
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:08:00 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 0.67 ; 2 ; 0.67 ; 1
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:09:00 ; 0.7 ; 0.7 ; 0.6422 ; 0.6422 ; 16 ; 0.67157 ; 4
AAPL ; NASDAQ ; 20200128; ; 10:10:00 ; 0.7 ; 0.7 ; 0.7 ; 0.7 ; 1 ; 0.7 ; 1
```

The whole code I am using for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

print("Converting Timezone")

TEMP = pd.read_csv("Temp\\data.csv", sep=";")

#Removing Whitespaces
TEMP.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)
TEMP['Ticker'] = TEMP["Ticker"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Exchange'] = TEMP["Exchange"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Date'] = TEMP["Date"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Time'] = TEMP["Time"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Open'] = TEMP["Open"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Open'] = TEMP["Open"].astype(float)
TEMP['High'] = TEMP["High"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['High'] = TEMP["High"].astype(float)
TEMP['Low'] = TEMP["Low"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Low'] = TEMP["Low"].astype(float)
TEMP['Close'] = TEMP["Close"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Close'] = TEMP["Close"].astype(float)
TEMP['Volume'] = TEMP["Volume"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Volume'] = TEMP["Volume"].astype(float)
TEMP['VWAP'] = TEMP["VWAP"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['VWAP'] = TEMP["VWAP"].astype(float)
TEMP['Trades'] = TEMP["Trades"].astype(str).str.strip()
TEMP['Trades'] = TEMP["Trades"].astype(float)
TEMP.drop(columns = ['None'], inplace=True)

#converting dates, here is where I get the error (after print(TEMP))
TEMP["Datetime"] = TEMP["Date"].astype(str) + ' ' + TEMP["Time"].astype(str)
print(TEMP)
TEMP["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(TEMP["Datetime"])
TEMP["Datetime"] = TEMP["Datetime"].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Paris').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
TEMP["Datetime"] = TEMP["Datetime"].dt.tz_localize(None)
TEMP["Datetime"] = TEMP["Datetime"].astype(str)
new = TEMP["Datetime"].str.split(" ", n=1, expand=True)
TEMP["Date"] = new[0]
TEMP["Time"] = new[1]
TEMP.drop(columns =["Datetime"], inplace = True)
TEMP["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(TEMP["Date"])
TEMP['Date'] = TEMP.Date.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
TEMP["Date"] = TEMP["Date"].astype(str)
TEMP.drop_duplicates(subset=['Ticker', 'Exchange', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades'], keep='first')
TEMP.sort_values(by=['Date', 'Time'])

print("Dataframe")
print(TEMP)
```

EDIT:

Alright so making the following changes to the code seemed to fix the issue, which I think is verry weird but ill go with it.

```
TEMP["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(TEMP["Datetime"], errors='coerce')
```

adding `errors='coerce'` to this line fixed me not getting the error. This however should return NaT values for each line that had an error, but I'm not getting any, so all my data gets converted and no errors are found (atleast thats what I think this means), eventhough it previously said it had errors. I'm happy that the issue is resolved, but still flabbergasted about the solution.

also setting `dtype='object' seemed to help here, probably because I have a large data set.

Comment: Could you share some lines of your `csv` file to have a look to the input data ? Please also include the line that raise an error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my post with a sample and the entire code

Comment: The problem is there are no hypens b/w dates in your csv file. Pandas supports the format "%Y-%m-%d". Did the dataset by default had no hypens or you did some preprocessing on it?

Comment: @amber than you for your comment. I get the data in this format. at first I tried converting it to the format you suggested, but that leads to issues at other places in my code (different script), so I figured keeping it like this is easier since then it doesn't cause issues there. Also, the same format also used to work previously, the errors I only got since yesterday eventhough I have been using the code like this for a couple more days than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a lot to say.

First, `pandas` automatically detects the type for each columns. With your csv data, everything was correctly imported, to the exception of the column `Date` which was imported as `int64`. The whole paragraph called `# removing white spaces` is then not necessary. Note that the code is 100% functionnal, if you keep this paragraph.

Also consider the option `dtype='object'` in the read_csv function. So every column will be set as `object` data.

Second, regarding your question, when I remove the 1st paragraph and run merely this batch of code, I do manage to get a `Datetime` column of type `datetime64[ns]`:

```py
TEMP = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";")
TEMP.drop(columns = ['None'], inplace=True)
TEMP["Datetime"] = TEMP["Date"].astype(str) + ' ' + TEMP["Time"].astype(str)
TEMP["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(TEMP["Datetime"])
print(TEMP)
print(TEMP.dtypes)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, this does clear things up a bit. After just using the codesnippet you gave, I still get the same error. When i change the dtype to 'object' as you suggested, i get a different error: "Unknown string format: nan nan". Even if I split my large csv files into chunks, i get this error for each chunk

Comment: It was working with the example data you provided. Did you try with a smaller csv files ?

Comment: Yes, I split the csv files in 4 different files and I got the error for each file. I now tried your 'dtype='object'' solution, and I added 'errors='coerce'' to the pd.to_datetime line, which seemed to do the job. The weird thing is that this 'coerce' line should return the error values as NaT, but I am not getting any back, so there is nothing wrong with my data. I'm surprised this did the job, so consider the topic solved. Ill update my post and upvote your answer